# Add svg (component) as property in object

Tags: javascript, html, svg, svelte, sveltekit

I have this.

```
let items = [
{ name: 'John', age: 27, icon: 'svg?' },
{ name: 'Peter', age: 54, icon: 'svg?' }
]
```

Then:

```
{#each items as item}
<div>{item.name}</div>
<div>{item.icon}</div>
{/each
```

I use Svelte and I import my svg icons with

```
import Something from '../svg/something-icon.svg';
```

Normally in my .svelte I would use then:

```
<Something />
```

and this works well.

However, how do I know add my svg as a property in my object where it says `icon: 'svg?'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a component class in a variable, you can render using something like:

```
<svelte:component this={item.icon} />
```

[Docs](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-svelte-component)

(If the property only contains an SVG string, you can use `{@html item.icon}`)

Comment: this `<svelte:component this={item.icon} />`     gives me the error that it is not a valid SSR component. So I did this... `import Something from '../svg/something-icon.svg';` and then `let items = [
{ name: 'John', age: 27, icon: 'Something' },
{ name: 'Peter', age: 54, icon: 'xxx' }
]` and then... `<svelte:component this={item.icon} />` and then the error came.

Comment: I said *if it is component class*. if you do not have a plugin that converts SVGs to components and the result of the import is a string, you should use `{@html}`. `'Something'` is just a string, if anything it would have to be `icon: Something`.